# How to Count consecutive dates

Tags: t-sql, count, sequential

I'm look for a query in T-Sql to count the number of consecutive dates, backwards where the pop is the same, starting at the latest date and stopping when there is a gap in the date.

This is an example of the data:

```
Name    village Population  Date
Rob     village1    432     01/07/2013
Rob     village2    432     30/06/2013
Rob     village3    432     29/06/2013
Rob     village3    432     28/06/2013
Rob     village3    432     27/06/2013
Rob     village3    430     26/06/2013
Rob     village3    430     25/06/2013
Rob     village3    430     24/06/2013
Rob     village3    430     23/06/2013
Rob     village3    425     22/06/2013
Rob     village3    422     21/06/2013
Rob     village3    422     20/06/2013
Rob     village3    411     19/06/2013
Harry   Village1    123     01/07/2013
Harry   Village2    123     30/06/2013
Harry   Village3    122     29/06/2013
Pat     Village1    123     01/07/2013
Pat     Village2    123     30/06/2013
Pat     Village3    123     29/06/2013
Pat     Village4    100     20/06/2013
Tom     Village1    123     01/07/2013
Tom     Village2    123     30/06/2013
Tom     Village3    123     29/06/2013
Tom     Village4    123     28/06/2013
```

I would expect to get the following results:

```
Rob 5
Harry 2
Pat 3
Tom 3
```

The data should be more complex, but there will be 1000's of rows, 100's per person and groups of pop with consecutive dates, but i only want the first set of consecutive dates with the same pop, from the latest downwards.

Comment: In absence of a primary key this is not possible.  Is there a PK?

Comment: There is no PK, but a composite key from Name, Village and Date can be used.

Comment: Then how would you order them?  Without PK or unique Key that assigns order you cannot perform any order based analysis.  A select statement is not guaranteed to return rows in the order they are present in the table.  If you have to put date in the order by then surprise - you will get date in that order.

Comment: We will order them by name and date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with dd as 
(
   select distinct * from table
);
    select name, max(count) + 1
    from 
    (
       select t1.name, t1.village, t1.pop, count(*) as count
       from dd t1 
       join dd t2 
         on t2.village = t1.village
        and t2.pop  = t1.pop 
        and t2.pop  = t1.pop 
        and t2.date = dateadd(day,-1,t1.date)
       group by t1.name, t1.village, t1.pop
    )  dates
    group by name
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. - Sorry for my ignorance, I see I've been voted down. I'll just ask the moderators to delete the post. 

The problem with the above solution, is it will return multiple results per player, if they have groups of pop that are the same.. I.E pop is the same for 2 days, then increases and then another group of 3 are the same.. will return 2 answers.

Comment: Then add village.  Apply yourself.  You had no duplicate dates in the sample.  Just do a select distinct to eliminate the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with a as
(
select name, village, population, date, cast(date as datetime) + dense_rank() over(partition by Population, name order by date desc) grp
from <your table>
), b as
(
select name, village, population, date, dense_rank() over (partition by name order by grp desc) rk
from a
)
select name, count(distinct date) from b
where rk = 1
group by name
```